# How do I use c++ stringstream to convert a string to a double? The string is a nonstandard scientific notation that does not contain 'e'

Tags: c++, sstream

I have a code that looks like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s = "-1.42-14";
    stringstream ss;
    ss << s;
    double a ;
    ss >> a;
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
}
```

I run this code and I get `a = -1.42`，but I want `a = -1.42e-14`.
what should I do

Comment: Add the missing `e` in the input string?

Comment: And if you want to convert a string to a floating point number, with actual validation then I suggest you use [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead.

Comment: Regex replace `(\\d)([-+])(\\d)` with `$1e$2$3` or such.

Comment: `The string is a nonstandard` thus, you can't use standard tools and you have to write your own conversion function.

Comment: I actually added the missing `e`, but maybe it wasn't robust enough. Anyway, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read in both parts separately and combine them manually:

```
std::string s = "-1.42-14";
std::istringstream ss(s);

double mantissa;
ss >> mantissa;

double exponent;
ss >> exponent;

double a = mantissa * std::pow(10.0, exponent);

std::cout << "a = " << a << '\n';
```

**Output:**

```
a = -1.42e-14
```

**Note:** *Given that floating point types are only an approximation of real numbers, when you perform the same calculation by different means, you often arrive at a slightly different value.*

Comment: note that if accuracy is important then this method won't necesarily produce exactly the same answer as parsing the string directly: https://godbolt.org/z/soWE3PYaW

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, was also going to comment on that. The difference is small but detectable in this case.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, I added a comment.